# Mutually exclusive buttons in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a group of buttons that in an ngFor component i want to be mutually exclusive. I want to design it that when i click the first button in a row , it cant be clicked again till i click the corresponding button in that same row. This is my Typescript snippet and the functions i created;

```
showTime(staff){
        staff.time = new Date();
     }
     displayTime(staff){

        staff.times = new Date();
    }
```

This is my HTML snippet;

```
    <tbody>
               <tr *ngFor="let staff of staffs" class="m-1 p-1 bg-light">
                    <td>
                        {{staff.name}}  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            {{staff.department}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button [disabled]="!flagOne" (click)="showTime(staff)">Click</button>
                        <span *ngIf="staff.time">
                            Time: {{staff.time | date: 'shortTime'}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button [disabled]="!flagTwo" (click)="displayTime(staff)">Click</button>
                        <span *ngIf="staff.times">
                            Time: {{staff.times | date: 'shortTime'}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
```

My array looks like this:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    staff: [
        { id: 1, name: "xxx", department: "Development",
           role: "Team Lead", time: null },
        { id: 2, name: "xxx", department: "Development",
           role: "Back End", time: null },
        { id: 3, name: "xxx", department: "Security",
           role: "Front End",time: null },
        { id: 4, name: "xxx", department: "Infrastructure",
           role: "Corper", time: null },
        { id: 5, name: "xxx", department: "Infrastructure",
           role: "xxx", time: null },
           { id: 6, name: "xxx", department: "Management",
           role: "Assistant", time: null },
           { id: 7, name: "xxx", department: "Management",
           role: "Director", time: null }
                ],
    entries: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two flags in your component, control the `disabled` attribute of the buttons with these flags. Set them while calling `showTime()` and `displayTime()` methods.

.ts

```
 export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  staff = {time: null};
  flagOne = true;
  flagTwo = true;
  showTime(staff){
    this.staff.time = new Date();
    this.flagOne = false;
    this.flagTwo = true;
  }

  displayTime(staff){
    staff.times = new Date();
    this.flagTwo = false;
    this.flagOne = true;
  }    
}
```

.html

```
 <td>
      <button [disabled]="!flagOne" (click)="showTime(staff)">Button One!</button>
      <span *ngIf="staff.time">
          Time: {{staff.time | date: 'shortTime'}}
      </span>
  </td>
  <td>
      <button [disabled]="!flagTwo" (click)="displayTime(staff)">Button Two!</button>
      <span *ngIf="staff.times">
          Time: {{staff.times | date: 'shortTime'}}
      </span>
  </td>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwahcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It worked. But i don't want to disable all buttons in the column of a table . just the specific one i clicked

Comment: @EmekeObuseh: Please add the complete code, coz as far as I saw there are just two buttons in your question. Avoid asking XY problem like:  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @xyz, you can simply the code using an unique "flag". Well if you use a variable "buttonClicked", `<button (click)="buttonClicked=1" [disabled]="buttonClicked==1">click</button>`